# Overlay an iframe on another iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video, overlay

I have a javascript code, using which an iframe moves with mouse pointer. 
and when I slide mouse over another iframe (e.x youtube embed video), the iframe doesn't move with mouse while mouse pointer is on youtube video.

what can be done? thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var opacity = 1;
var time = 3500000;
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    (function openColorBox() {
        if ((document.getElementById) && window.addEventListener || window.attachEvent) {
            var hairCol = "#ff0000";
            var d = document;
            var my = -10;
            var mx = -10;
            var r;
            var vert = "";
            var idx = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
            var thehairs = "<iframe id='theiframe' scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' allowTransparency='true' src='b.html' style='margin: px 0px 0px px; position:fixed;width:200px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;border:0;opacity:" + opacity + ";filter:alpha(opacity=" + opacity * 100 + ");'></iframe>";
            document.write(thehairs);
            var like = document.getElementById("theiframe");
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(like);
            var pix = "px";
            var domWw = (typeof window.innerWidth == "number");
            var domSy = (typeof window.pageYOffset == "number");
            if (domWw) r = window;
            else {
                if (d.documentElement && typeof d.documentElement.clientWidth == "number" && d.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) r = d.documentElement;
                else {
                    if (d.body && typeof d.body.clientWidth == "number") r = d.body
                }
            }
            if (time != 0) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(like);
                    if (window.addEventListener) {
                        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouse, false)
                    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                        document.detachEvent("onmousemove", mouse)
                    }
                }, time)
            }

            function scrl(yx) {
                var y, x;
                if (domSy) {
                    y = r.pageYOffset;
                    x = r.pageXOffset
                } else {
                    y = r.scrollTop;
                    x = r.scrollLeft
                }
                return (yx == 0) ? y : x
            }

            function mouse(e) {
                var msy = (domSy) ? window.pageYOffset : 0;
                if (!e) e = window.event;
                if (typeof e.pageY == 'number') {
                    my = e.pageY - 0 - msy;
                    mx = e.pageX - 0
                } else {
                    my = e.clientY - 6 - msy;
                    mx = e.clientX - 6
                }
                vert.top = my + scrl(0) + pix;
                vert.left = mx + pix
            }

            function ani() {
                vert.top = my + scrl(0) + pix;
                setTimeout(ani, 300)
            }

            function init() {
                vert = document.getElementById("theiframe").style;
                ani()
            }
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
                document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse, false)
            } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                window.attachEvent("onload", init);
                document.attachEvent("onmousemove", mouse)
            }
        }
    })();
    var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 30;
    var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDay);
    document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString()
}
</script>

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sTesehdHbqs" style="display:block; position:static;"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: How can anybody know without providing us the code? We are not mind readers.

Comment: Please show you code.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your HTML, the best guess is: you're not going to be able to do this. The issue is that, once you move your mouse into an iframe that has an origin different from your page, mouse events will not fire out to your script, and therefore you won't be able to update the position of your iframe. DEMO: Note how the mouse coordinates stop updating once you move your mouse pointer inside the iframe.

```js
function mouseMoveListener() {
  var outputX = document.querySelector('#mouseX');
  var outputY = document.querySelector('#mouseY');
  return function(ev) {
    outputX.innerText = ev.clientX;
    outputY.innerText = ev.clientY;
  };
}

function test(ev) {console.log('ev::', ev.clientX);}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener());
```

```html
    <div>Mouse position:
      <span id="mouseX"></span>
      ,
      <span id="mouseY"></span>
    </div>

    
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

If you don't need to let your users interact with the content of the iframe, you can cheat this by overlaying a transparent div on top of the iframe. That prevents mouse events from "falling through" to the iframe beneath them, while still showing the content of the iframe. DEMO: But note that the iframe doesn't allow you to scroll, since mouse events (like clicks on the scroll bar or wheel events) are captured by the overlay div.

```js
function mouseMoveListener() {
  var outputX = document.querySelector('#mouseX');
  var outputY = document.querySelector('#mouseY');
  return function(ev) {
    outputX.innerText = ev.clientX;
    outputY.innerText = ev.clientY;
  };
}

function test(ev) {console.log('ev::', ev.clientX);}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener());
```

```css
#iframe-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#iframe-wrapper iframe {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#iframe-wrapper .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>Mouse position:
  <span id="mouseX"></span>
  ,
  <span id="mouseY"></span>
</div>

<div id="iframe-wrapper">
  <iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

However, if you're displaying a YouTube video, it's unlikely this will satisfy your requirements, since user interaction is a key part of the viewing experience.